# Extract a column name from a Pandas column index

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a function which takes `Pandas` columns to be plotted on a scatter graph. I'd like to use the names of the columns as axis labels. Here's an example of what I mean:

```
def plotscatter(x,y):
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    plt.xlabel(x)
    plt.ylabel(y)
plotscatter(df['1stcol'],df['2ndcol'])
```

I'd like to extract just the text in the inverted commas i.e. 1stcol and 2ndcol. If I use x and y as they are I get the column name followed by all of the values as an axis label.

Is there a built-in method or function for this? Like x.columnname()

Comment: Apart from my answer to your question, other suggestion: you can also use the `plot` method for this: `df.plot(x='1stcol', y='2ndcol', kind='scatter')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the columns names with `DataFrame.columns` or for a column `Series.name`. An example:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,4]], columns=['1stcol', '2ndcol'])

In [13]: df.columns
Out[13]: Index([u'1stcol', u'2ndcol'], dtype='object')

In [14]: df.columns[0]
Out[14]: '1stcol'

In [16]: df['1stcol'].name
Out[16]: '1stcol'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using `.columns` with the input, but as the input to the function is a column from a `DataFrame` i.e. `df['somecolumn']`. I get an attribute error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'column'`. Is there some way to work around this?

Comment: See my answer, I also inlcuded `.name` for columns (which are Serieses)

Comment: Sorry, my fault for not reading thoroughly. `.name` is exactly what I needed.